# How to preserve the case of a data attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute, jquery-data

The html object:

```
 <div data-myAttribute="test"></div>
```

The code:

```
 var $o = $("div");

 $.each($o.data(),function(k,v){
    console.log(k); 
    //writes 'myattribute' instead of 'myAttribute'
 });
```

How do I preserve the case of the attribute?

Comment: You should use `data-my-attribute` to get `.data('myAttribute')`

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7641551/4202224)

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you, that seemed to help me. Despite the fact it *can't be used* according to the answers.

Comment: @ControlFreak `data-my-attribute` is perfectly valid attribute name regarding spec: `For each name on the list, for each U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS
     character (-) in the name that is followed by a character in the
     range U+0061 to U+007A (U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A to U+007A
     LATIN SMALL LETTER Z), remove the U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character
     (-) and replace the character that followed it by the same
     character converted to ASCII uppercase.`

Comment: @A.Wolff  I'd put your comments as an answer, since it answers the intent of the OP (and also matches what I wanted)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your goal is to target `myAttribute` as key of `dataset` property, you should use `data-my-attribute`:

```
<div data-my-attribute="test"></div>
```

See following link regarding camelCased rule:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset

PS: as [Izkata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359388/how-to-preserve-the-case-of-a-data-attribute/27368507#comment-43191343) commented it:

> For reference for others, jquery also does conversion such that
>   $div.data('my-attribute') returns the same thing as
>   $div.data('myAttribute'). The vanilla javascript dataset property does
>   not do this.

Comment: I chose your answer because it was useful and did what I needed done. Thanks.

Comment: For reference for others, jquery also does conversion such that `$div.data('my-attribute')` returns the same thing as `$div.data('myAttribute')`.  The vanilla javascript `dataset` property does not do this.

Answer (score 39):

Valid HTML data attributes can't contain uppercase characters anyway:

From the [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes):

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the
>   hyphen, is XML-compatible, and **contains no characters in the range
>   U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z)**.

Answer (score 14):

You can't. Attribute names are always lowercase in HTML5.

Answer (score 5):

As an addendum to `@A. Wolff`'s answer, you can apply a `--` to the data attribute name if you want leading capitals.

```
<div data--my-attribute="test"></div>
```

Will result in a data key of `MyAttribute`