# Is there a simple/fast way to map "data-" attributes to mixed-case property names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, custom-data-attribute

I have a base plugin class I use as the basis of all my jQuery plugins. It is similar to the jQuery UI widget, but does a lot more heavy lifting for me.

I now wish to map `data-` attribute values, from the attached element, into any options passed to the plugin. This will allow the plugin to not only take the typical `options` object, but also allow data-driven override values on individual elements (a common requirement).

The problem I have is that my option properties are typically mixed case e.g. `MaxHeight`, but apparently the HTML specification *only allows lowercase characters* into `data-` attribute names.

As an example testbed: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/tfkrwq09/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test" data-DataTest="test2"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var object = {
    DataTest: 123
};
$.each($('#test').data(), function (k, v) {
    object[k] = v;
});

console.log(object.datatest); // test
console.log(object.DataTest); // 123
```

Desired result:

```
console.log(object.datatest); // undefined
console.log(object.DataTest); // test
```

I am after ways to map `data-` attributes to mixed-case properties, while retaining the current speed and simplicity (if possible).

Comment: I did a quick test based on the example in jQuery's doc for `data()`, it seems that if you set the data yourself that jQuery will retrieve it as it was written. Example: `$('#test').data({TEST: 1});` and then do `console.log(object.TEST);` and you will get `1`.

Comment: You have to use hyphen notation: `data-data-test="test2"` EDIT: in fact not for `DataTest` but that's quite why a property name shouldn't start with an uppercased letter

Comment: This is interesting, didn't realize it worked that way. Not only does it seem that uppercase letters are invalid, they "All ... get ASCII-lowercased automatically"

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359388/how-to-preserve-the-case-of-a-data-attribute

Comment: @A. Wolff: Very close. `that's-a-great-solution`... Just tried `data--data-test` and also got a leading uppercase char... please post as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See following link regarding camelCased rule: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset

So in your case, i'd use:

```
<div id="test" data--data-test="test2"></div>
```

To get:

`object.DataTest; //test2`

Comment: `data--data-test` will give get the leading capital I required (I guessed it might allow that and it worked). You may want to revise.

Comment: It's my C# tendency to use `ProperCased` property names. Not sure what the widest standard is for JS code :)

Comment: Most common standard for C# I see is `Property` = ProperCased, `Field` = lowerFirst

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie you are right indeed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: ...I may need to warp my coding to suit the most common JS naming standards (switching back and forth is a pain, hence liking TypeScript a lot) :)